# Using rz and sz under linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

Anyone knowns how to use rz and sz under linux shell? 
I can use it under sercurecrt, but not ubuntu shell. 
Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think these programs require an underlying terminal to implement the local end of the protocol. The shell you use is irrelevant.

Comment: For those (like me) who don't now immediately, what `rz` and `sz` is: _Zmodem File Transfer_ (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/run/apph_01.htm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, perhaps by typing the "**rz**" command at the console, perhaps you were trying to transfer a file via zmodem between two PCs directly from the console via a cross-over serial cable?

I've currently been trying to figure something like this out for myself, so will share what I've got, in-case it's what you were after.

I made two little scripts to help out:

script: "**zsend**"

```
#!/bin/sh

DEV=/dev/ttyS0

stty -F $DEV 115200
sz $1 > $DEV < $DEV
```

script: "**zrecv**"

```
#!/bin/sh

DEV=/dev/ttyS0

stty -F $DEV 115200
rz > $DEV < $DEV
```

Usage Example:

- Copy these scripts onto both PCs.
- Alter the "DEV" variable in each script to match your PC's serial device name (eg, for USB-serial ports, it might be "/dev/ttyUSB0")
- On PC1, type: **sudo zsend filename**
- On PC2, type: **sudo zrecv**

That's worked out for me.

Comment: Don't forget for more troubleshooting info you can use the verbose option. `rz -vvvvvvvvvv > $DEV < $DEV`. The 10 `v`'s will print out the bytes read in hex, if any were read.

Answer (score 5):

Get to know GNU Screen.

1.install GNU Screen

2.configure Screen by creating a .screenrc file in the root directory.

Write 'zmodem catch' into the .screenrc file.

3.run screen

4.

(1) Send a file from the remote host to the local host:

execute sz FILE from the command line

hit  when Screen brings up the default receive command

(2) Send a file from the local host to the remote host

execute rz from the command line

add local filename when Screen brings up the default send command, then hit